# Line Plot not Plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot some data, however it's not plotting. When I run my code, it just says "process finished", with no plot showing up. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any advice on how to fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import randint
import time
import datetime

Time = time.time()
fig = plt.figure()

x = []
y = []


def rand_num():
    while True:
        n = randint(1, 1000)
        n1 = randint(1, 1000)
        n2 = randint(1, 1000)

        def animate(i):

                x.append(time.time())
                # print(Time)
                y.append(n)
                # print(n)
                plt.plot(x, y, color='r')
                # plt.plot(x, n1, color='g')
                # plt.plot(x, n2, color='b')
                euler = []
                return


        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  interval=1000)
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the function at the end of the code:

```
rand_num()
```

[image]

For changing values try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import randint
import time
import datetime

Time = time.time()
fig = plt.figure()

x = []
y = []

def rand_num():

    def animate(i):

        n = randint(1, 1000)
        n1 = randint(1, 1000)
        n2 = randint(1, 1000)
        x.append(time.time())
        y.append(n)
        plt.plot(x, y, color='r')
        euler = []

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  interval=1000)
    plt.show()

rand_num()
```

[image]

Comment: Also, I assume that you want to move the random number generation inside the `animate` function

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see that it's plotting, but shouldn't the line be changing as it's picking random numbers between 1 - 1000?

Comment: I see, that is a different question but please try what I suggest in the Edited answer.